# Extract List elements of specific types with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, extract

I have a List of objects and I have to write a method which extracts some elements in accordance to an input parameter which is an array of Type. The function must return an array of elements from the list each of them being an instance of one element from the array of types. At the same time those elements must be removed from the container list but only if they ALL do exist in the list. Type comparison is achieved by `Type.IsInstanceOfType(o)` method.

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
class C : A {}
class D : A {}

public static A[] ExtractElements (List<A> list, Type[] specifiers) {...}

Type[] specifiers1 = new Type[2] {typeof(D), typeof(B)};
Type[] specifiers2 = new Type[3] {typeof(C), typeof(A), typeof(D)};
Type[] specifiers3 = new Type[2] {typeof(A), typeof(A)};
Type[] specifiers4 = new Type[2] {typeof(C), typeof(C)};

List<A> list = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result1 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers1);

list  = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result2 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers2);

list  = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result3 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers3);

list  = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result4 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers4);
```

Results of this code fragment would be:

```
  result1 is {D, B}, list is {A, C, A}  
  result2 is {C, B, D}, list is {A, A}  
  result3 is {B, A}, list is {D, C, A}  
  result4 is empty array, list is {B, A, D, C, A}
```

As a seperate effort would it be possible to write a similar ExtractElements method which only returns non-empty array if the list contains items of requested types whose order in the list corresponds to the order of elements in the types input array like the following

```
Type[] specifiers5 = new Type[2] {typeof(B), typeof(D)};
Type[] specifiers6 = new Type[2] {typeof(C), typeof(B)};

List<A> list = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result5 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers5);

list  = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};
A[] result6 = ExtractElements (list, specifiers6);
```

Results of this code fragment would be:

```
result5 is {B, D}, list is {A, C, A}  
result6 is empty array, list is {B, A, D, C, A}
```

I know that `LINQ` is the way to implement this but unfortunately I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public IEnumerable<TType> ExtractElements<TType>(IEnumerable<TType> list, IEnumerable<Type> specifiers) {
   var specifiersList = specifiers.ToList();

   return list.Where(t => specifiersList.Any(s => s.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetType())));
}

var specifiers5 = new[] {typeof(B), typeof(D)};
var list = new List<A> {new B(), new A(), new D(), new C(), new A()};

// you can call ToArray() if you want but ForEach won't be available on that
// and you'll need a standard foreach() loop
var result5 = ExtractElements(list, specifiers5).ToList();

result5.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

For [more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) on `Type.IsAssignableFrom()`

Comment: Appears to do the trick. I've got a console app with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect fit for [`Enumerable.OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

Comment: I think you may have hit it right on the head. Deleting my answer. For some reason I was afraid to use that method, but new about it all along. I was thinking of calling Enumerable.Cast<T>, which I knew would potentially beak at runtime.

Comment: Oh wait, except the only problem is that he has multiple types he wants to check for.

Comment: Ah, right. That does throw a wrench in things doesn't it. (upvoted your answer)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you everything you wanted.  I added an optional argument to the `ExtractElements` method that lets you enable/disable the order matching.

```
public static A[] ExtractElements (List<A> list, Type[] specifiers, bool orderMatters = false)
{
    var allFound = true;
    var listBackup = list.ToList(); // Make a backup copy   
    var returnList = new List<A>();
    var earliestMatch = 0;

    foreach (var spec in specifiers)
    {
        var item = list.FirstOrDefault (i => spec.IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType()));
        if (item != null)
        {
            var matchPosition = list.IndexOf(item);
            if (orderMatters && matchPosition < earliestMatch)  // we have an out of order match
            {
                allFound = false;
                break;
            }
            earliestMatch = matchPosition;
            list.Remove(item);
            returnList.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            allFound = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!allFound)
    {
        // Can't just assign list to listBackup because we have to update the 
        // underlying values not the reference that was passed to the function.
        list.Clear();
        listBackup.ForEach(i => list.Add(i));
        returnList.Clear();
    }

    return returnList.ToArray();
}
```

I suggest grabbing a copy of [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to help you test any `LINQ` statements and to learn `LINQ` in general.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh wow...I just realized he wants to modify the incoming collection. I'll just let you take it from here.

Comment: Yeah, that made it so much more awkward.